# Невозможно задержаться в выпадающем меню

Tags: html, css, css3, list

Скажите, пожалуйста! При наведении мышки на выпадающие меню открываются ссылки, но при попытке пройти по ссылкам меню сразу закрывается, невозможно сфокусироваться на ссылках. Как это можно устранить? Вот ссылка http://jsfiddle.net/Arty21/y9DYh/.

```css
#nav {
    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
}
#nav, #nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    width:200px;
}
#nav ul {
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
}
#nav li {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
#nav ul li {
    margin-top:-23px;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
}
#nav li a {
    background-color: #3366ff;
    color: #3366ff;
    display:block;
    font-family: Arial, Geneva, Verdana;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:28px;
    outline:0;
    padding-left:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li a.sub {
    background:#d4d5d8 url("../img/down.gif") no-repeat;
}
#nav li a + img {
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
    height:28px;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:200px;
}
#nav ul li a {
    background-color:#eee;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    color:#000;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:22px;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#ddd;
    color:#444;
}
#nav ul li a img {
    background: url("../img/bulb.png") no-repeat;
    border-width:0px;
    height:16px;
    line-height:22px;
    margin-right:5px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:16px;
}
#nav ul li:nth-child(odd) a img {
    background:url("../img/bulb2.png") no-repeat;
}
#nav a:hover ~ ul li {
    margin-top:0;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s linear;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s linear;
    -o-transition: 0.4s linears;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s linears;
    transition: 0.4s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1">1</a>
            <img src="../img/up.gif" alt="" />
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 5</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1">2</a>
            <img src="../img/up.gif" alt="" />
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 5</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1">3</a>
            <img src="../img/up.gif" alt="" />
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 6</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 7</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 8</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 9</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 10</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1">4</a>
            <img src="../img/up.gif" alt="" />
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 6</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 7</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 8</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 9</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 10</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1">5</a>
            <img src="../img/up.gif" alt="" />
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 6</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 7</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 8</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 9</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 10</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1">6</a>
            <img src="../img/up.gif" alt="" />
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 6</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 7</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 8</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 9</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 10</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1">6</a>
            <img src="../img/up.gif" alt="" />
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 6</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 7</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 8</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 9</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 10</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1">7</a>
            <img src="../img/up.gif" alt="" />
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 6</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 7</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 8</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 9</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 10</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jg2t2/ посмотрите такой вариант

Comment: Вариант классный! Но только не пойму где здесь прицепить width чтобы задать ширину?

Comment: Нашел как установить ширину! А что значит ячейка с цифрами?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p3ZZR/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/y9DYh/8/

```css
#nav {
    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
}
#nav, #nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    width:200px;
}
#nav ul {
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
}
#nav li {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
#nav ul li {
    margin-top:-23px;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
}
#nav li a {
    background-color: #3366ff;
    color: #3366ff;
    display:block;
    font-family: Arial, Geneva, Verdana;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:28px;
    outline:0;
    padding-left:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li a.sub {
    background:#d4d5d8 url("../img/down.gif") no-repeat;
}
#nav li a + img {
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
    height:28px;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:200px;
}
#nav ul li a {
    background-color:#eee;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    color:#000;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:22px;
}
#nav ul li:hover a {
    background-color:#ddd;
    color:#444;
}
#nav ul li a img {
    background: url("../img/bulb.png") no-repeat;
    border-width:0px;
    height:16px;
    line-height:22px;
    margin-right:5px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:16px;
}
#nav ul li:nth-child(odd) a img {
    background:url("../img/bulb2.png") no-repeat;
}
#nav li:hover > ul li {
    margin-top:0;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s linear;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s linear;
    -o-transition: 0.4s linears;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s linears;
    transition: 0.4s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1">1</a>
            <img src="../img/up.gif" alt="" />
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 5</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1">2</a>
            <img src="../img/up.gif" alt="" />
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 5</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1">3</a>
            <img src="../img/up.gif" alt="" />
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 6</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 7</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 8</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 9</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 10</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1">4</a>
            <img src="../img/up.gif" alt="" />
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 6</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 7</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 8</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 9</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 10</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1">5</a>
            <img src="../img/up.gif" alt="" />
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 6</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 7</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 8</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 9</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 10</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1">6</a>
            <img src="../img/up.gif" alt="" />
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 6</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 7</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 8</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 9</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 10</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1">6</a>
            <img src="../img/up.gif" alt="" />
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 6</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 7</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 8</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 9</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 10</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1">7</a>
            <img src="../img/up.gif" alt="" />
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 6</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 7</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 8</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 9</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 10</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```